# How to get values from foreach loop of php in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm Working on a plugin in Wordpress in which i'm storing values in new table which is created on plugin activation its working perfectly.

Now I fetched values from table like following

```
     <tbody>
                <?php
                global $wpdb;
                $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ajc_images");
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    ?>
                    <tr id="list_item">
                        <td width="12%">
                            <img src="<?php echo $row->ajc_img_path ?>" width="100">
                        </td>
                        <td width="22%">
                            <input type="text" class="img_link" value="<?php $row->ajc_img_link ?>" size="30">
                            <input type="hidden" class="ajc_field_id" value="<?php echo $row->ajc_img_id ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td width="26%">
                            <textarea rows="3" class="img_description"><?php $row->ajc_img_description ?></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td width="22%">
                            <input type="text" class="img_title" value="<?php $row->ajc_img_title ?>" size="30">
                        </td>
                        <td width="20%">
                            <input type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
                            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
</tbody>
```

after fetching the data I display the values in form of listing.

Now I want to update values of input fields and textarea through ajax for which I wrote following code

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajc_update_values', 'ajc_update_value');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajc_update_values', 'ajc_update_value');

add_action("admin_head", "ajc_input_ajax");
function ajc_input_ajax()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery("#update").click(function () {
                var id = jQuery('.ajc_field_id').val();
                var update_link = jQuery('.img_link').val();
                var update_desc = jQuery('.img_description').val();
                var update_title = jQuery('.img_title').val();

                alert(id);

                var data = {
                    action: 'ajc_update_values',
                    ajc_id: id,
                    ajc_update_link: update_link,
                    ajc_update_desc: update_desc,
                    ajc_update_title: update_title
                };

                alert(data.toSource());

                jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function (result) {
                    // alert(result);
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

//Updating values in database
function ajc_update_value()
{
    $id = $_POST['ajc_id'];
    $link = $_POST['ajc_update_link'];
    $desc = $_POST['ajc_update_desc'];
    $title = $_POST['ajc_update_title'];

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update(
        'wp_ajc_images',
   array(
        'ajc_img_title' => $title,
        'ajc_img_description' => $desc,
        'ajc_img_link' => $link
    ),
        array('ajc_img_id' => $id)
    )
    die();
    return true;
}
```

When I click on first item's update button it alerts me right id eg. (12) and update it, but when I click on rest of the item's update button it alerts me first item's id (12) and data is not updated.

Hope you'll understand my question.

Comment: `var id = jQuery('.ajc_field_id').val();` you are selecting an item via a class name. You cannot know wich one in your document will be selected because several item match. In fact, it will gives you the first one it reaches. That is the explaination why it allways  return id 12. In the same way, due to your loop, each row will have the same ID `list-item`, remember that ID must be uniques.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. add id to every fields like  `id="img_link_<?php echo $row->ajc_img_id; ?>"`

> HTML code

```
    <tbody>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ajc_images");
foreach ($result as $row) {
?>
<tr id="list_item">
    <td width="12%">
        <img src="<?php echo $row->ajc_img_path ?>" width="100">
    </td>
    <td width="22%">
        <input type="text" id="img_link_<?php echo $row->ajc_img_id; ?>" class="img_link" value="<?php $row->ajc_img_link ?>" size="30">
        <input type="hidden" class="ajc_field_id" value="<?php echo $row->ajc_img_id; ?>">
    </td>
    <td width="26%">
        <textarea rows="3" id="img_description_<?php echo $row->ajc_img_id; ?>" class="img_description"><?php $row->ajc_img_description ?></textarea>
    </td>
    <td width="22%">
        <input type="text" id="img_title_<?php echo $row->ajc_img_id; ?>" class="img_title" value="<?php $row->ajc_img_title ?>" size="30">
    </td>
    <td width="20%">
        <input type="submit" data-id="<?php echo $row->ajc_img_id; ?>" id="update" value="Update">
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

> Script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery("#update").click(function () {

    var id =jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
    var update_link = jQuery('#img_link'+id).val();
    var update_desc = jQuery('#img_description'+id).val();
    var update_title = jQuery('#img_title'+id).val();

    alert(id);

    var data = {
        action: 'ajc_update_values',
        ajc_id: id,
        ajc_update_link: update_link,
        ajc_update_desc: update_desc,
        ajc_update_title: update_title
    };

    alert(data.toSource());

    jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function (result) {
        // alert(result);
    });
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying values based on a class name and there could be many elements with same class name. What you need to do is target specific `<tr>` and get values from that `<tr>` only.

So your jQuery code should look like this:

```
jQuery("#update").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').find('.ajc_field_id').val();
    var update_link = $(this).parents('tr').find('.img_link').val();
    var update_desc = $(this).parents('tr').find('.img_description').val();
    var update_title = $(this).parents('tr').find('.img_title').val();

    alert(id);

    var data = {
      action: 'ajc_update_values',
      ajc_id: id,
      ajc_update_link: update_link,
      ajc_update_desc: update_desc,
      ajc_update_title: update_title
    };

    alert(data.toSource());

    jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function (result) {
      // alert(result);
    });
});
```

> You just have to add **$(this).parents('tr').find** before selecting values from every element.